# Review list - catalog_product_view.xml - QUESTION

Tags: product, theme, review

I am working on an issue for a few days and can't make it working.

I have a custom theme and was able to fix possitions using catalog_product_view.xml (move method on the element).

The problem I had with review list. I can't move it anywhere. I would like to move it on the right column, next to the picture.

I know how to move it above the container with review.phtml file, but I don't know how to move it inside the container (right column). I was thinking of using Jquerry to hack the DOM, but I am sure there must be another solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code
Add this in `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <container name="product.info.details" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product info detailed" after="product.info.extrahint">
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
            <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="Magento_Review::product/view/list.phtml" ifconfig="catalog/review/active"/>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" ifconfig="catalog/review/active"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

If `after="product.info.extrahint"` not work then try `after=="extrahint"`

Comment: It works! You are a genious!

Answer (score 0):

**You can change the destination like the below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title"/>
    <move element="product.info.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="product.price.final"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. Checked GOOGLE - chatGPT, everything and I did not find a solution. That's why I've decided to ask the community.